# Unable to locate the EL RI expression factory

Tags: jsp, jsf, el

I am getting the following exception in my application.

> com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:
>   It appears the JSP version of the
>   container is older than 2.1 and unable
>   to locate the EL RI expression
>   factory,
>   com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.  If
>   not using JSP or the EL RI, make sure
>   the context initialization parameter,
>   com.sun.faces.expressionFactory, is
>   properly set.

How to set the EL details in the `web.xml`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception is telling that JSP 2.1 is required. You need to ensure that your `web.xml` is declared as Servlet 2.5 or newer, and that your servletcontainer supports it (Tomcat 6, Glassfish 2, JBoss AS 5, etc, or newer). JSP 2.1 goes hand in hand with Servlet 2.5. A proper Servlet 2.5 declared `web.xml` starts as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

If you're using an older versioned servletcontainer which you can really not upgrade to at least a Servlet 2.5 compatible one, then you need to let us know first which one it is so that we can if possibly post more suited answers/workarounds.

Comment: After I update the web.xml, then also getting the same error.

Comment: But, I have not added the attribute version="2.5". Is it necessary? I just copy pasted from another source. Which doesn't have that attribute.

Comment: Either the environment does not support Servlet 2.5 at all or the classpath is polluted with old versioned libraries. First, what environment (servletcontainer/server) are you using? Tomcat 6.0? Tomcat 5.5? Glassfish v2? Glassfish v3? Etcetera.

Comment: Sorry..I have specified the attribute version="2.5"

Comment: Then the only reasonable reason left is that your classpath is messed up. You should **never** touch `JRE/lib` and `JRE/lib/ext` folders. You should **never** add/remove servletcontainer specific libraries in `Tomcat/lib` and `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib`. If there are any, you need to cleanup it.

Comment: I have solved the problem. EL API is old version. After updating to the new version its working.

Comment: That's a servletcontainer-specific library. You should not have the need to update it. It should already be included in `Tomcat/lib` and kept untouched there. If there is any in `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib`, you need to remove it. Take a look in `Tomcat/lib` of a fresh Tomcat installation and compare its contents with `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib`. If there are any similarly named libraries in webapp like `jsp-api`, `servlet-api`, etc, etc, you need to **remove** them all from the `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib`. They are supposed to be provided by the servletcontainer itself, not by your webapp.

Comment: @BalusC I have followed your instructions, (the el-api is in the class path of tomcat lib). But still the exception is there. I am using tomcat 7.0. Before this, it was working fine on tomcat 6.0

Answer (score 5):

This is because latest el jar is not in classpath.
It worked for me too

(Reference)Please refer the link 
[JSF 2.0 + Tomcat : It appears the JSP version of the container is older than 2.1…](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-tomcat-it-appears-the-jsp-version-of-the-container-is-older-than-2-1/)

Comment: I tried BalusC tip first, but the error still kept coming.
After adding the latest el jar, the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the Web.xml, it worked for me.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to remove following in Web.xml , it worked for me.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```